# My NodeJS Child Process doesnt run my python file when i am using PM2 but works fine when i execute them in nodemon

Tags: python, node.js, pm2

My Node Js code:

```
    app.post('/python', chamandoPython)

    async function chamandoPython(req, res) {
      var process = spawn('python', ["./PythonServices/main.py", 
       "./uploads/"]).on('error', function( err ){ throw err })
      process.stdout.on('data', async function (data) {
        await res.send(data.toString())
      })
      process.stderr.on('data', async function (data) {
        console.log("stderr" + data.toString())
      })
     }
```

When i run this file js through nodemon, works great but when is executed in PM2, give me this error:

```
    $Error: spawn python ENOENT
    $  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    $  at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    $  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
    $errno: 'ENOENT',
    $code: 'ENOENT',
    $syscall: 'spawn python',
    $path: 'python',
    $spawnargs: [ './PythonServices/main.py', './uploads/' ]
    $}
```

I dont have experience at posting questions in stackoverflow, so if someone needs more information, just write in comments

Comment: ENOENT means the file or directory you are trying to access doesn't exist. How are your files and folders structured? Your path seems to be incorrect.

Comment: But the same script works when i use nodemon, just dont work in PM2. When i execute "Index.js" file with nodemon, works great, but when i execute in PM2, doenst work.Sorry for my english, this is not my native linguish

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Instead of screenshots of your code, please type your code into your question, formatting it with `backticks`. The same would go for your traceback message. Both these help the community in answering your question.

Comment: OK! I made some changes on the question, now is better?